# Magento drop price by percentage after one month

Tags: php, magento

I have a requirement to drop the price of an item after 2 weeks, then again after a month by a percentage for a Magento site.

I am new to Magento and was wondering what the best way of going about this was?

From the research I have done I can see that Magento has a nice way of handling catalog price rules, but I can't see how my requirement fits with it.

The other solution I was thinking of was a CRON job that ran and called a custom module.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Thanks Mike, but I thought it was pretty specific, I want to know best practice for implementing a time based percentage price reduction in Magento, I have outlined the approach I think is right and was looking to know if it fits with best practice, is that not specific?

Comment: I think most people just do this type of administration manually since you are talking about just two discrete price changes over a month—not exactly high overhead. However, I know there is a start date for Catalog Price Rules, and you can apply to percentage of price. So why not just create two rules that drop the price on specific days?

Comment: The actual rule is on a product after a time period, so 2 weeks after a product is listed and isn't sold it's price drops by a percentage, you can see how this would a bit of a maintenance nightmare. (thanks for the help btw)

Comment: @Burt - I guess I have a different idea of maintenance nightmares because that doesn’t seem like much trouble to add Catalog Price Rules at two week intervals in the future from the day that the admin sets the product active. I am assuming by “isn’t sold” you are referring to there being only one qty of the product to sell, so it is then out of stock once someone purchases it.

Comment: The cron job idea is a wise choice - the process would be to check the created date of each product on a daily basis and update the price (or special_price) attribute if the time has elapsed beyond the breakpoints you specify.

Comment: @fantasticrice if a user was adding products daily, they would have to log into the system daily to update prices from 2 weeks ago and 4 weeks ago, it isn't a solution. If the admin gets sick or goes on holiday it doesn't work. Unless I am missing something? You are right it is only 1 item per product.

Comment: @MattO thanks for confirming that Matt, without knowing how Magento works that is the best solution I could come up with, wanted to see if I was on the right lines.

Comment: @Burt - I figured the admin would just set the Catalog Price Rules to begin on the future dates when they made the product active. In that case each product takes two steps but can be done at the same time.